# Using existing SQL Server Db table as store for Identity Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have built a web app that I only want certain users to access. The list of authorized users is just a list of emails that live in a SQL Server db table. I wanted to use Microsoft Identity to have a login page be prompted when the site is open to have the user log in using their email address and if it matches what is in my current table, to let them into the site. I was following a tutorial that was using Microsoft Identity's default tables that it creates, but was wondering if there is a way to customize it to look at an already existing table for authorization. I am very new to web development so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Would I have to create a custom store? or or use a controller? I am using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core for the db connection. I am also using the MVC paradigm.